# FFMPEG: is it possible to record 1920x1080 screen with DSHOW?

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I am currently working on a screen recorder in VB.net and i need ffmpeg to record my screen. I have the following ffmpeg code now:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -framerate 30 -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le "output result file.mkv"
```

This works fine, but it only records a part of my screen. I already tried the registry keys (They weren't made, so i made them myself), but it also didn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Show full console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wanted to share this with you who have the same problem.

***Problem solved***

just right-click ffmpeg.exe. 2: Select properties 3: Select the compatibility 4: Check The High DPI windows thing and you're done

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for me:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array" RECORD.mp4
```

Here, "Microphone Array" is my default audio device, and the name is retrieved using:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

The advantage of above command is that it allows you to record multiple screens at once, or even one out of two screens, simply by changing the offset (`-offset_x` & `-offset_y`).