# ffmpeg and uscreencapture not taking full screen

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screen, fullscreen, video-capture

I want to record my screen full screen with modest command below. My screen resolution is 1920x1080

C:\Users\Totzfreelance\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)"  -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p c:\Users\Totzfreelance\testing3.mp4

but the video result dimension always 1280x720. There is part of screen not captured. I want it to be 1920x1080.

Comment: What log you mean?

Comment: You need more precise what you are taking. I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was solved here.

[FFMPEG: is it possible to record 1920x1080 screen with DSHOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783444/ffmpeg-is-it-possible-to-record-1920x1080-screen-with-dshow)

> just right-click ffmpeg.exe. 2: Select properties 3: Select the compatibility 4: Check The High DPI windows thing and you're done

I set "Override High DPI Scaling Behavior". Scaling performed by, "Application".

This works for me.